# Python PULP How To Get Block of Values Same

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am trying to find a way in PULP to code such that all the values within a block specified by the IF statement at end (i.e. if j >= 7 and j <= 21) are the same.

I am not sure where to start as I am more familiar with coding in Xpress Mosel and not PULP language.

```
model += pulp.lpSum([YALL[(i,j)] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE) if j >= 23]) == pulp.lpSum([YALL[(i,j)] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE) if j <= 24])
```

The code above is a very rudimentary way I have to set the periods of 23 and 24 equal to each other.  I am trying to have it such that I can specify the start period (i.e. 7) and the end period (i.e. 22) and have all values between those periods equal to one another.  Code I have so far is below but doesn't do what I need.

```
model += pulp.lpSum([YALL[(i,j)] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE) if j >= 7]) == pulp.lpSum([YALL[(i,j)] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE) if j <= 21])
```

Comment: Are you able to share a [mcve]? It would make it a lot easier to suggest the best way to do what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add constraints `YALL[(i,j)] == YALL[(i,j+1)]` for `j` in 7, ..., 20:

```
for i in range(YPER):
    for j in range(7, 21):
        model += YALL[(i,j)] == YALL[(i,j+1)]
```

I might be getting the PuLP syntax slightly wrong but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Works perfectly! I knew it had to be something along these lines but wasn't sure.  Thanks!!